# regex: Matching a word in a line omitting commented lines

Tags: regex, ansible

For the following data

```
#128.134.71.53 fs-1a07881b.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com varlogbackup
128.134.71.14  fs-a669fea7.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com confluence-shared
128.134.71.152 fs-1a07881b.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com varlogbackup
```

I would like to match the file system IDs from non-commented lines. In the above example we would match `fs-a669fea7` from the second line and `fs-1a07881b` from the third.

`(fs-[\w]+)` gets the matches I want, but I also want to omit the commented line. I know `^[^#]` will omit a commented line, but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

Using `^[^#].+(fs-[\w]+)` includes what I want with a capture group getting the `fs-` word, but I'm not sure how to return just the capture group. Or if this is the best technique for matching.

The pattern `(^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ +)` will capture the IP addresses skipping the commented one (using multiline and matching the start of a line with `^`).

I can use positive lookbehind `?<=` to skip the IP addresses. The following works when testing in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/), but isn't supported in my environment and throws an error.

```
(?<=^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ +)(fs-[\w]+)
```

I'm using the regex in Ansible:

```ansible
  vars:
    efs1:
      ip: 128.134.71.152
      fsid: fs-1a07881b
      mount: varlogbackup
    efs_list:
      - "{{ efs1 }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Set /etc/hosts entries
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        regexp: '({{ item.fsid }})'
        line: "{{ item.ip }} {{ item.fsid }}.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com {{ item.mount }}"
      loop: "{{ efs_list }}"
```

Comment: You could start matching from the start of the string `^(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s+(fs-\w+)` See https://regex101.com/r/VBSSK1/1

Comment: Why do you need to "return just the capture group"? Return the whole match, then use the capture group in further processing.

Comment: Or do this in two steps. First filter out all the comment lines, then search for the pattern in the rest.

Comment: What language/tool/platform/framework/library are you using?

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77360849/edit) the relevant information to the question, not here in comments. But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.